# How to display equivalent octal values for the numbers 1 through 256

Tags: java, binary, hex, octal

I am making this program to help me when I convert numbers to different types. I have an array that displays all binary values for every number between 1 and 256, as well as an array that does the same thing for all Hexadecimal Values. The problem I am having is displaying the octal values.

When I first wrote this program I had each number entered manually and then the calculations were done all in the program and displayed the conversions. Now I decided I just want to show a table of each number from 1 to 256 with their corresponding binary, hex, and octal values.

I have no problem displaying the values for binary and hex but when I get to Octal, everything is displayed as a zero if I don't use user input. When user input is added, every value for the octal array is the same as whatever value I entered.

I just need someone to look over my code and show me where my logic is off.

```
import java.util.*;
public class NumberConverter 
{
    static int num = 0;
    static String bin = "" + num, hex, oct;

    public static void main (String [] args)
    {

/**
 * Allows for user input to enter a number between 1 & 256 which is then passed to three methods      for conversion into binary, hexadecimal, and octal values     
 */
//          Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
//          System.out.print("Please enter a positive integer between 1 & 256: ");  //prompts the          user for a positive integer between 1 & 256
//          num = scan.nextInt();
//      
//          if(num <= 0 || num > 256)
//          {
//              System.out.println("Invalid number.\n");
//              //if the number entered by the user is 0 or less, or greater than 256, an Invalid message is displayed.
//          }
//          
//          else 
//          {
//              System.out.print("\nDecimal to Binary Conversion: ");
//              NumberConverter myBinary = new NumberConverter();       //creates a new object    called myBinary from the NumberConverter Class
//              System.out.println(myBinary.toBinary(num));             //takes the myBinary     object and modifies it using the toBinary method
//          
//              System.out.print("Binary to Hexadecimal Conversion: ");
//              NumberConverter myHex = new NumberConverter();          //creates a new object called myHex from the NumberConverter Class
//              System.out.println(myHex.binaryToHex("" + num));        //takes the myHex object and modifies it using the binaryToHex method
//      
//              System.out.print("Binary to Octal Conversion: ");
//              NumberConverter myOctal = new NumberConverter();        //creates a new object called myOctal from the NumberConverter Class
//              System.out.println(myOctal.binaryToOctal(num));         //takes the myOctal object and modifies it using the binaryToOctal method
//          }

/**
 * Creates an array to store and display all hexadecimal values for the numbers 1 through 256   
 */
    String [] hexConv = new String [257];
    NumberConverter myHex = new NumberConverter();
    for(int count = 1; count < hexConv.length; count++)
    {
        hexConv[count] = myHex.binaryToHex("" + count);
    }       
/**
 * Creates an array to store and display all Octal values for the binary values of the numbers 1 through 256    
 */
    String [] octConv = new String [257];
    NumberConverter myOctal = new NumberConverter();
    for(int count = 1; count < octConv.length; count++)
    {
        octConv[count] = myOctal.binaryToOctal(num);
    }

/**
 * Creates an array to store and display all binary values for the numbers 1 through 256
 * and prints the contents of all three arrays  
 */
    String [] binConv = new String [257];
    NumberConverter myBinary = new NumberConverter();
    System.out.println("\n\n#\tBinary\t\t   Hexadecimal\t       Octal");
    for(int count = 1; count < binConv.length; count++)
    {
        System.out.print(count + ":\t");
        binConv[count] = myBinary.toBinary(count);
        System.out.println("\t\t\t" + hexConv[count] + "\t\t" + octConv[count]);
        System.out.println("--------------------------------------------------------------");
    }       
}

public String toBinary (int num)
{
    String remainder = "" + num % 2;

    if (num < 1) 
    {
        return "" + num;
    }

    bin = remainder; //remainder value is stored as the value of bin
    toBinary(num >> 1);
    System.out.print(remainder);
    return " ";

}

public String binaryToHex(String binaryValue)
{
    String result = ""; 
    int n = Integer.parseInt(binaryValue);
    int remainder = n % 16;

    if (n == 0) 
    {
        return "";
    } 

    else 
    {
        switch (remainder) 
        {
            case 10:
                result = "A";
                break;
            case 11:
                result = "B";
                break;
            case 12:
                result = "C";
                break;
            case 13:
                result = "D";
                break;
            case 14:
                result = "E";
                break;
            case 15:
                result = "F";
                break;
            default:
                result = remainder + result;
                break;
        }
        hex = binaryToHex(Integer.toString(n / 16)) + result;
        return hex;
    }
}


public String binaryToOctal(int decimalValue)
{
    decimalValue = Integer.parseInt("" + num, 8);
    return "" + decimalValue;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
   // Main.java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {   
    String num = "1110";

    int dec = Integer.parseInt(num,2);

    String oct = Integer.toOctalString(dec);

    System.out.println("Binary " + num + " in Octal radix is "+ oct );

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are in

```
public String binaryToOctal(int decimalValue){
    decimalValue = Integer.parseInt("" + num, 8);
    return "" + decimalValue;
}
```

- ignoring the parameter
- parsing num, which always remains at 0

and so you'll always get 0. Changes:

```
for(int count = 1; count < octConv.length; count++){
    octConv[count] = myOctal.binaryToOctal(count);   // <-- pass in count
}

public String binaryToOctal(int decimalValue){
    return String.format( "%o", decimalValue );
}
```

I admit, it's no big feat to use formatted printing for base conversion. There is an algorith that should be used for all bases, 2, 8, 10, 16, when going from a binary (int) value to a String value representing that value in some base.

**Later**

This is the algo I was referring to, good for any base up to 16.

```
private static String digits = "0123456789ABCDEF";
public static String convert( int num, int base ){
    if( num == 0 ) return "0";
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    while( num > 0 ){
        sb.insert( 0, digits.charAt( num % base ) );
        num /= base;
    }
    return sb.toString();
}

public static void main( String[] args ) throws Exception {
    for( int i = 0; i < 100; i++ ){
        System.out.println( i + " " + 
                           convert( i, 2 ) + " " +
                           convert( i, 8 ) + " " +
                           convert( i, 10 ) + " " +
            convert( i, 16 ) );
    }
}
```